# How to display single post from custom post type loop?

Tags: custom-post-types, single

Sorry for silly question, I'm newbie in Wordpress and PHP. I created a custom post type using [this](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-guide-to-wordpress-custom-post-types-creation-display-and-meta-boxes--wp-27645) tutorial. The category page is working normally, but the single is displaying all posts from category. I need to display only current post on single.php template. How can I do this?
Here is the code of my single.php file in movie reviews plugin.

```
    <?php
get_header(); ?>
<section id="content">
    <div class="wrap-content blog-single">
    <?php
    $mypost = array( 'post_type' => 'movie_reviews', );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $mypost );
    ?>
    <?php if ($loop->have_posts()) : while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
       <?php the_title( '<h1>','</h1>' );  ?>
             <div class="post-thumbnail">
 <?php the_post_thumbnail(array(250, 250)); ?>
 </div>
            <div class="entry-content"><?php 
            the_content(); ?></div>
        </article>
         <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</section>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

And this code defines template files:

```
function include_template_function( $template_path ) {
    if ( get_post_type() == 'movie_reviews' ) {
        if ( is_single() ) {
            // checks if the file exists in the theme first,
            // otherwise serve the file from the plugin
            if ( $theme_file = locate_template( array ( 'single-movie.php' ) ) ) {
                $template_path = $theme_file;
            } else {
                $template_path = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/single-movie.php';
            }
        } else {
             if ( $theme_file = locate_template( array ( 'movie-category.php' ) ) ) {
                $template_path = $theme_file;
            } else {
                $template_path = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/movie-category.php';
            }
        }
    }
  return $template_path;
}
add_filter( 'template_include', 'include_template_function', 1 );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your single.php is coded in a way that show all posts like archive, it needs to be modified.

To fetch current post, try something like that instead:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<section id="content">
    <div class="wrap-content blog-single">

    <?php  while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
            <?php the_title( '<h1>','</h1>' );  ?>
            <div class="post-thumbnail"><?php the_post_thumbnail(array(250, 250)); ?> </div>
            <div class="entry-content"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
        </article>
    <?php endwhile; ?>

    </div>

</section>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation for it: https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Type_Templates

single-{post_type}.php

If your custom post type were 'product', and/or query_var = "product", WordPress would look for single-product.php to display the single or permalink of the post.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I need. The single post template defines correctly, but it display all posts from category. I need to display only current post. For example in site.com/movie-reviews/first-review/ must display only "first-review" post content, but now displaying all posts from "movie-reviews".

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `posts_per_page` argument in your WP_Query and setting it to `1`:

```
$mypost = array( 'post_type' => 'movie_reviews', 'posts_per_page' => 1);
$loop = new WP_Query( $mypost );
// ...stuff and things
```

Comment: Thanks, but it display only first post. I need to display current post.  For example in site.com/movie-reviews/first-review/ must display "first-review" post content.